# Multiple Rails Application docker up not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have two Rails 6 application and I am trying to deploy in `aws ec2` instance with different port `8080` and `8081` but when I trying to run `docker-compose up -d` it start one rails application successfully and if I tries to run `docker-compose up -d` for second application, It make first application down and make another application up on particular Port

Below is my docker configuration for two applications.

> Application 1

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  app:
    image: "dockerhub_repo/a_api:${TAG}"
    # build:
    #   context: .
    #   dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: a_api_container
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
      - sidekiq
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: staging
  database:
    image: postgres:12.1
    container_name: a_database_container
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  sidekiq:
    image: "dockerhub_repo/a_api:${STAG}"
    container_name: a_sidekiq_container
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: staging
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0-alpine
    container_name: a_redis_container
    volumes:
      - "redis:/data"
volumes:
  redis:
  db_data:
```

> Application 2

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  app:
    image: "dockerhub_repo/b_api:${PPTAG}"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: b_api
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
  database:
    image: postgres:12.1
    container_name: pp_database
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0-alpine
    container_name: pp_redis
volumes:
  db_data:
```

This Configuration works very well in local machine. It start both application in local on different port but it has some issue on aws ec2. I am not sure is any thing wrong in configuration?

Comment: Are the two `docker-compose.yml` files in directories with the same name; something like `/app-a/docker` or `/app-b/docker`?  That could confuse Compose.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes first one was in app1/backend and second one was in app2/backend.. I renamed that and it works like charm.. Thanks alot.. But I did not get the thing like how folder name can cause the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose has the notion of a *project name*.  If you add or delete containers from a `docker-compose.yml` file, it looks for existing containers that are labeled with the project name to figure out what needs to change.  The project name is also included in the Docker names of containers, networks, and volumes.

You can configure the project name with the [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) or the `docker-compose -p` option.  If you don't configure it, it defaults to the base name of the current directory.

You clarify in a comment that the two `docker-compose.yml` files are in directories `app1/backend` and `app2/backend`.  Since the base name of those directories are both `backend`, they have the same project name; so if you run `docker-compose up` in the `app2/backend` directory, it finds the existing containers for the `backend` project, sees they don't match what's in the `docker-compose.yml` file, and deletes them (even though you as the operator think they belong to the other project).

There are a couple of ways to get around this:

- Rename one or the other directory; maybe move the `docker-compose.yml` files up to the top-level `app1` and `app2` directories.
- In one or both directories, create a [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) that sets `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=app1`.  (Note that file is checked in the current directory, not necessarily the directory that contains the `docker-compose.yml` file.)
- Set and change an environment variable `export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=app1`.
- Consistently use an option `docker-compose -p app1 ...` with *all* Compose commands.